# Connections and curvature

Tags: rotations, curvature

I have data defined on $\mathbb{R}^3 \times S^2$, i.e. $S(x,y,z,\theta,\phi)$. For any two points $p$ and $p'$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ I also have a rotation $R_{pp'} \in SO(3)$ that best aligns the data on the sphere from those two points. Is there some sort of curvature (or equivalent) that can measure "the strength" of much I have rotated? Perhaps there can be a connection defined from that rotation from which curvature can be calculated, I have heard about $SU(2)$ connections from physics but not sure if it applies here.

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "strength", which is not at all clear from your question. What do you need this strength value for? what do you want it to indicate to you? Would the angle of rotation suffice? Or do you need it to also indicate something about the axis of rotation?

Comment: I am looking for a scalar that is similar (or identical) to curvature. For e.g. for 2d surface embedded in 3d we can see how quickly the normal vector changes and define curvature that way. Would I do the same here, like I can apply $R(\alpha,\beta,\theta)$ rotation to the z-unit vector and look at the magnitude of change after rotation? I feel like there is a more systematic way to do this...

Comment: Okay, but the only thing you've said about what you are wanting to measure the "curvature" of is that it is "data". That doesn't tell me anything. All I know is that you have some rotation matrix. All rotations in 3-dimensional space are characterized by a unit vector representing the axis about which the rotation occurs, and a value from $0$ to $\pi$ representing the angle of counter-clockwise rotation about that axis vector (if the rotation needs to be greater than $\pi$, then you choose the opposite axis vector instead). Is that angle of rotation about the axis sufficient?

Comment: Just the angle about the axis of rotation won't be sufficient because angle of the axis of rotation itself is also important... The data itself is not really important what I have is an object that tells how to rotate an "internal sphere" from one point to the next.

Comment: You cannot compress the information in 3 independent parameters into a single value in any continuous fashion without loss. Any "strength" value you define is going to be constant over a 2-dimensional collection of rotations. So you won't be able to determine the rotation from this number. You say the orientation of the axis and the angle of the rotation are both important. But how is their importance related? What makes one axis orientation stronger than another?

Comment: Actually I think your earlier comment makes sense. Just the angle of rotation about the axis of rotation is sufficient and simple. The angle of the axis itself is not that relevant -- it could be very large but then the actual rotation about it could be very small.

Comment: Especially since "angle of the axis" doesn't make sense unless you have some "standard direction" you are comparing it to. And that is only sensible if the standard direction has some particular importance to your data. If you just chose the $z$-axis, for example, but the $z$-direction has no particular association with your data, then such an angle would be arbitrary, not helpful.